# How to get a particular column value from pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF in which data is displayed in a table. In this table, I have multiple columns, but I want to get particular column values as a list. Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
    text.Append(currentText);
}
pdfReader.Close();
return text.ToString();
```

With this code, I get all of the text of the PDF, but I want a particular column of data. The column name is "Date".

Comment: Your use case was exactly why the iText add-on [pdf2Data](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data) was created for. My advice: use pdf2Data, because if you want to write an add-on such as pdf2Data yourself, you'll have to spend several months in development.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more complicated than you would think.
A PDF document does not (always) contain structure information. It only has instructions that a viewer needs to render the document.

Imagine something like:

> go to 50, 50
>   use font Helvetica Bold
>   draw the glyph for character 'H'
>   go to 56, 50
>   draw the glyph for character 'e'

These instructions do not even need to appear in logical reading order.
As a result, determining what makes up a logical table, based on instructions is very hard.

Possible approach (if your table contains enough lines):

- use IEventListener to be notified of PathRenderInfo and TextRenderInfo
- gather PathRenderInfo into lines
- gather lines into clusters if (and only if) they cross at 90° angles
- determine number of rows and columns from such line clusters
- assume something is a table if (and only if) it consists of enough rows and columns and has some text in it